# Getting the signature key was not found error using Keycloak with .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, keycloak

This is my .NET Core WebAPI authentication configuration:

```
            services
                .AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultForbidScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.MetadataAddress = "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/{my_realm}/.well-known/openid-configuration";
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/{my_realm}";
                    options.Audience = "{my_audience}";
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidAudience = "{my_audience}",
                        ValidIssuers = ["http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/{my_realm}", "https://localhost:8080/auth/realms/{my_realm}"]
                    };
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.SaveToken = true;
                });
```

I'm getting the following error:
`www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="The signature key was not found"`

Changing log level to DEBUG gives the following error:
`Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10500: Signature validation failed. No security keys were provided to validate the signature.`

There seems to be a problem with the value of `options.MetadataAddress`.

If it helps, both my app and Keycloak are running in Docker.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible , please provide more code details and debug details if possible . Make sure that the issuer and audience in your configuration match the token issuer uses .

Comment: @FengzhiZhou updated my question details.

Comment: Please check the configuration of your keycloak to see if the settings match. The metadata endpoint should return a JSON object that includes the `jwks_uri` , Try access the uri manually. Check your placeholders passed correctly, I can only get them in .net8 locally.

Comment: @FengzhiZhou I can access the metadata endpoint manually and it does return that JSON object with `jwks_uri`. Have doubled checked the placeholders and they all seem fine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could try yo Authenticate on keycloak using [our package](https://github.com/Wissance/Authorization), that allows to do this in 1 line:

```cs
private void ConfigureWeb(IServiceCollection services)
{

     KeyCloakServerConfig authConfig = BuildKeyCloakConfig();
     services.AddKeyCloak(authConfig);
}
```

`BuildKeyCloakConfig` is a function that build config from `appsettings.json`, but you could hardcode it simply for tests, i.e.:

```cs
private KeyCloakServerConfig BuildKeyCloakConfig()
{
    KeyCloakServerConfig config = new KeyCloakServerConfig("https://auth.yourdomain.com", "myRealm",
                                                                                                   KeyCloakClientType.Confidential, "myClient", "aaadf6a5-abbb-bbbc-b644-c1291fbfffff");
}
```

However, package allows only to authenticate by Token and nor supporting complicated scenarios. Also it should be mentioned that It was tested on KeyCloak 16 version, in newer version URLs difer from 16. We have an issue to support any version based on .well-known URL config.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the only `AddJwtBearer` properties you should set are `Authority` and `Audience`.

What should happen next is that your .NET API calls the discovery endpoint at the path `.well-known/openid-configuration`. Then the `jwks_uri` value is stored.

When you make API calls, the JWKS URI is called occasionally to get token signing public keys in a JSON Web Key Set (JWKS).

At runtime your API will then look at the `kid` value in received JWT headers, then look for a corresponding entry in the JWKS.

So you need to trace both the JWKS and JWT values to resolve your problem. My [blog post](https://authguidance.com/jwt-access-token-validation/) has further info on troubleshooting this type of problem.